# Specflow - How to move back to a previos step

Tags: testing, bdd, specflow

lets say this is my .featurefile , behind very step a method is binded..

```
Given The system administrator sends a list of Tracks
And The system is at CreateCWRFile method
And The system sends "name", "caeID" & "ver" to generate HDR Line   
Then The system generates GRH Line
Then The system generates track Revision Line   
Then The system generates track SPU Line
Then The system generates track SPT Line
Then The system generates and verifies SWT, PWR & SWR Lines each writer of track
```

let's say my test is at line number 5 i.e Step#5 and on some condition I want to come back to Step#2, How to do it..

Comment: This is not supported in specflow/gherkin. The step execution is sequential. You cannot have loops or branches. But why do you want to go back? I think you should create two different scenario one where the condition is true with a given set of step and one where the condition is false with the different set of steps..

Comment: I said "Ouch - antipattern" loud to myself when I read that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of repeating [Specflow step definition mapping with wildcard attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276505/specflow-step-definition-mapping-with-wildcard-attribute)  I think you are struggling because of what you are trying to achieve.

SpecFlow is good at describing;

- the state your system should be in - i.e. `Given`
- the operation you want to perform - i.e. `When`
- and the what the state should look like afterwards i.e. `Then`

So it may be that your example above has mixed up some of the `Then`s and `When`s.

As [nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv) points out in the comment, you probably should have more than one scenario to handle the branching. Have a look at [How to run gherkin scenario multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17325243/how-to-run-gherkin-scenario-multiple-times) for an example.

Your only other option would be to build your scenario from multiple steps and test you are in the right state each time, e.g.

```
Given the traffic light is red
When the light changes
Then the light should be amber
When the light changes
Then the light should be green
When the light changes
Then the light should be amber
When the light changes
Then the light should be red
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: the problem is i have long algorithm to generate a file, he algo uses various methods, those methods need to be checked, if i make a step for each method, i can not loop, and if i put the whole algo or the portion of algo behind one step then i am putting a lot only in one step...